# Accessing array outside of a Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, request-promise

I am trying to build an array of objects with various key values via some basic web scraping with **NodeJS**. For the next steps of my codebase i need to access the 'built' Array outside of the parent function which as you will see is:

```
rp.post(login)
```

Please note that I am using **express, request-promise & cheerio** as my main npm dependencies.

```
let orderArray = []; // Create Empty Array   

// Login
rp.post(login, function(err, res, body) {

    // Set Cookie Jar
    cookieJar = res.headers['set-cookie'];

    // Get Order Numbers
    rp(getOpenOrders).then(function ($) {

        // Check Amount of Open Orders
        let openOrderTableLength = $('tbody tr').length;

        // Build Out Information
        for (let i = 0; i < openOrderTableLength; i++) {

            let order = {
                vendor: "example vendor",
                vendorNum: $('a.show-progress-on-click').eq(i).text(),
                vendorNumLink: "https://www.vendor.com." + $('a.show-progress-on-click').eq(i).attr('href'),
                status: $('td.w200:nth-of-type(5)').eq(i).text(),
                dates: {
                    ordered: $('td.w100:nth-of-type(3)').eq(i).text(),
                    eta: "TBA",
                    shipped: "TBA",
                    arrived: "TBA",
                },
                courier: "TBA",
                trackingNum: "TBA",
                dropShip: false,
                items: []
            }

            if (order.status === "Backorder") {

                // Get details from specific
                rp({
                    uri: order.vendorNumLink,
                    cookie: cookieJar,
                    transform: body => cheerio.load(body)
                })


                .then(function ($) {

                    // Get length of items within
                    let backOrderItemsTableLength = $('tbody tr').length;

                    // Build out all the items
                    for (let j = 0; j < backOrderItemsTableLength; j++) {
                        let orderItem = {
                            sku : "TBA",
                            description: "TBA",
                            orderQty: "TBA",
                            allocQty: "TBA",
                            bOrderQty: "TBA",
                            eta: $('td:nth-of-type(6)').eq(j).text(),
                            unitCost: "TBA",
                            subTotal: "TBA",
                        }
                        order.items.push(orderItem);
                    }

                    orderArray.push(order);

                    console.log(orderArray) // Displays a filled array

                })
            }
        }
    })
});

console.log(orderArray) // Returns an empty array
```

As you will see in the last section of this code, I've marked where the array is working and where i need to access it outside of the parent function.

```
                    orderArray.push(order);

                    console.log(orderArray) // Displays a filled array

                })
            }
        }
    })
});

console.log(orderArray) // Returns an empty
```

I am asking for pointers to access the 'Built' array outside of the built out functions, in addition to this can someone provide some information around appropriate times to complete **returns**, **callback()** or **return callback()** which I'm assuming will solve my problem here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the last `console.log()` straight after the `rp.post(...)`? Because if so, the result is as expected: you initialize an empty array, then set the function as rp's POST method handler and right afterwards print the array which is still empty, as the handler function was not yet called, therefore the array still wasn't populated.

Comment: Yeah I realised my mistake! After scratching my head for a few moments, I sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - So I just figured this out, I still don't fully grasp the use cases for **returns, callback() or return callback()**, however, I did figure out what I needed to do here:

First - I wrapped my code around a **named function** like this:

```
function getInfo (callback){

    // Insert all my original code here

};
```

Secondly - I added **callback();** to the section where the built array was logging correctly as such:

```
                }

                orderArray.push(order);
                callback();

            })
```

Thirdly - I called my now named function again with an anonymous function as such:

```
getInfo (function(){
    console.log(orderArray);
});
```

When I started my NodeJS application, it logged the information from where I needed it.

I'm still open for tips to structure my code better, however, this has fixed my issues for now in case someone else has runs into the same type of problem.